# Is there an option to include external file in Mermaid Markdown?

Tags: markdown, mermaid

I would like the ability to include external .mmd file inside markdown file, but can't find any documentation on including external files.

I'm using VSCode Markdown with Mermaid extension, it is working properly when the markdown embed mermaid source in a code block, but I want to use external Mermaid file. Something like the example below:

```
mermaid {% include diagram.mmd %}
```

Is anyone familiar with such capability?

Comment: "I'm aware it's possible to embed Mermaid in Markdown"—it depends what you mean by "embed" and "Markdown". Markdown itself can hold Mermaid source in a code block, but it doesn't do anything special with it. Some tools add support for rendering Mermaid (and other stuff). What is the specific Markdown processor that you're using?

Comment: I'm using VSCode Markdown with Mermaid extension, it is workin properly when the markdown embed mermaid source in a code block, but I want to use external Mermaid file.

Something like the example below:

```mermaid
{% include diagram.mmd %}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/plamentotev/be495e81abd52dc10e7dd51fbb71dd8c